# Using + instead of \; in find -exec

Tags: bash, find, exec

I understand that using + rather than \; in a find command with -exec can speed things up because with \; the target of -exec is executed once for each result of the find command, whereas with + the target of -exec is executed "as needed."

This code works as expected and processes all subdirectories:

```
find "${directory}" -iname "*.jpg" -type d -prune -exec bash -c 'myscript "{}"' \;
```

But this code does NOT work:

```
find "${directory}" -iname "*.jpg" -type d -prune -exec bash -c 'myscript "$@"' bash {} +
```

It processes only one directory rather than all of them.

I'm obviously missing something about the proper syntax of using + when calling a function.

Comment: Can you be more explicit (with an example) about what the second one does vs what it should do?